# React Apollo: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'refetch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a function that has a bit of a promise chain going on, but that's besides the point.

When I run a certain mutation's `refetch`, it gives me `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'refetch' of undefined`.

The strange part is that if I remove a mutation before it, it will work. So here's the code:

```js
Promise.all(this.props.questionnaireData.map(({ kind, id }): Promise<any> => {
    const responses = this.props.formData[kind];
    return this.props.updateQuestionnaire(id, responses);
})).then(() => {
    this.props.finishAssessment(this.props.assessmentId)
        .then(() => {
            track('Assessment -- Finished', {
                'Assessment Kind' : this.props.assessmentKind,
                'Assessment Id'   : this.props.assessmentId,
            });
            if (this.props.assessmentKind === 'INITIAL_ASSESSMENT') {
                this.props.getCompletedInitialAssessment.refetch().then(() => {
                    Router.replace(routes.LoadingAssessmentResults.to, routes.LoadingAssessmentResults.as);
                });

                this.submitEmailNotifications();
            } else if(this.props.assessmentKind === 'GOAL_CHECK_IN') {
                Router.replace(routes.MemberProgressDashboard.to, routes.MemberProgressDashboard.as);
            } else {
                Router.replace(routes.MemberDashboard.to, routes.MemberDashboard.as);
            }
        });
});
```

The error happens at `this.props.getCompletedInitialAssessment.refetch()`, to which I don't know why. However, when I remove `this.props.finishAssessment(this.props.assessmentId)`, only then the refetch will work.

Basically:

```js
Promise.all(this.props.questionnaireData.map(({ kind, id }): Promise<any> => {
    const responses = this.props.formData[kind];
    return this.props.updateQuestionnaire(id, responses);
})).then(() => {
        track('Assessment -- Finished', {
            'Assessment Kind' : this.props.assessmentKind,
            'Assessment Id'   : this.props.assessmentId,
        });
        if (this.props.assessmentKind === 'INITIAL_ASSESSMENT') {
            this.props.getCompletedInitialAssessment.refetch().then(() => {
            Router.replace(routes.LoadingAssessmentResults.to, routes.LoadingAssessmentResults.as);
            });

            this.submitEmailNotifications();
        } else if(this.props.assessmentKind === 'GOAL_CHECK_IN') {
            Router.replace(routes.MemberProgressDashboard.to, routes.MemberProgressDashboard.as);
        } else {
            Router.replace(routes.MemberDashboard.to, routes.MemberDashboard.as);
        }
});
```

will make refetch work. Otherwise it complains that it doesn't know what refetch is.

For Apollo, I'm using the graphql HOC, and it looks like this:

```js
graphql(getCompletedInitialAssessment, {
    name    : 'getCompletedInitialAssessment',
    options : { variables: { status: ['Finished'], limit: 1 } },
}),
graphql(updateQuestionnaire, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
        updateQuestionnaire: (id, responses) => {
            let normalized = {};

                for (let res in responses) {
                    let num = +responses[res];
                    // If the value is a stringified numuber, turn it into a num
                    // otherwise, keep it a string.
                    normalized[res] = Number.isNaN(num) ? responses[res] : num;
                }

                const input = {
                    id,
                    patch: { responses: JSON.stringify(normalized) },
                };

                return mutate({
                    variables: { input },
                });
            },
        }),
    }),
graphql(finishAssessment, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
        finishAssessment: (id) => {
            const input = { id };

            return mutate({
                variables      : { input },
                refetchQueries : ['getMemberInfo'],
            });
        },
    }),
}),
```

What I've tried is even rewriting this to use async/await, but the problem still happens:

```js
try {
    await Promise.all(this.props.questionnaireData.map(({ kind, id }): Promise<any> => {
        const responses = this.props.formData[kind];
        return this.props.updateQuestionnaire(id, responses);
    }));
    const finishAssessmentRes = await this.props.finishAssessment(this.props.assessmentId);
    console.log(finishAssessmentRes)

    if (this.props.assessmentKind === 'INITIAL_ASSESSMENT') {
        const res = await this.props.getCompletedInitialAssessment.refetch();
        console.log(res);
        this.submitEmailNotifications();
        Router.replace(routes.LoadingAssessmentResults.to, routes.LoadingAssessmentResults.as);
    } else if(this.props.assessmentKind === 'GOAL_CHECK_IN') {
        Router.replace(routes.MemberProgressDashboard.to, routes.MemberProgressDashboard.as);
    } else {
        Router.replace(routes.MemberDashboard.to, routes.MemberDashboard.as);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

I honestly don't know what's happening or why refetch wouldn't work. Would refactoring into hooks help? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: The error isn't really about refetch, it's telling you that there's no `this.props.getCompletedInitialAssessment` to call refetch on.

Comment: Understandably. I don't know why that's happening once `finishAssessment` is called. Does it overwrite `getCompletedInitialAssessment`?

Comment: Well, I assume `getCompletedInitialAssessment` is part of the state of a parent being passed down into the component as prop? How does it get changed? And when? Are you aware that setting the state is async?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/)

> The config.props property allows you to define a map function that takes the props... added by the `graphql()` function (`props.data` for queries and `props.mutate` for mutations) and allows you to compute a new props... object **that will be provided to the component that `graphql()` is wrapping**.
>
> To access props that are not added by the `graphql()` function, use the `ownProps` keyword.

By using the `props` function, you're telling the HOC which props to pass down either to the next HOC or to the component itself. If you don't include the props that were already passed down to it in what you return inside props, it won't be passed to the component. You need do something like this for every `props` function:

```
props: ({ mutate, ownProps }) => ({
  finishAssessment: (id) => {
    //
  },
  ...ownProps,
}),
```

Composing HOCs is a pain and the `graphql` HOC is being deprecated anyway in favor of hooks. I would strongly advise migrating to the hooks API.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn’t work, but I think you’re right with migrating to hooks. I’m going to try and do that in the grand scheme of things.